# Randomizing a dictionary in python

Tags: python, random, dictionary

I know you might say that dictionaries are not in any order naturally, but I have a large dictionary keys are numbers and some string as their values. The keys start from 0. for example: `x={0:'a',1:'b',2:'c'}`. I am using `.iteritems()` to go over my dictionary in a loop. however, this is done in the exact order of the keys `0,1,2`. I want this to be randomized. so for example my loop prints this: `1:'b',2:'c',0:'a'`. i need help. thanks

Comment: "I want this to be randomized."  Why?

Comment: In my case, I have a large dictionary of network targets. I want them to be scanned in a random order to reduce possible load on the network targets where there are multiple ports being scanned on the same host. Because in the input list they are in order of IP then port, I need to randomise this somewhere.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use `random.shuffle`. Also, the key iteration order of a dictionary is not guaranteed by any means - you just happened to get (0, 1, 2).

```
import random
keys = my_dict.keys()
random.shuffle(keys)
for key in keys:
    print key, my_dict[key]
```

Comment: Given how dictionaries are implemented usually it doesn't change, though, unless you add entries.

Comment: On a related note. `collections.OrderedDict` is the correct one to use if you want it to stay act more like *e.g.* PHP associative arrays.